# Error "cannot resolve method"

Tags: java, oop, vector

I am creating a `Vector` class for educational purposes.  This class has standard getters & setters, and now I want to add support for adding two vectors.

When I try to call `result.setVectorValue`, I get the error *cannot resolve method setVectorValue*.  How can I overcome my trouble?

Here is the full code of my class:

```
public class Vector <T1> {
    private T1[] vectorArray;

    public Vector(){
    }

    public Vector(T1[] a){
        this.vectorArray = a;
    }

    public void setVector(T1[] a){
        this.vectorArray = a;
    }

    public void setVectorValue(T1 value, int index){
        this.vectorArray[index] = value;
    }

    public T1[] getVector(){
        return this.vectorArray;
    }

    public T1 getVectorValue(int index){
        return this.vectorArray[index];
    }

    public int getVectorLength(){
        return this.vectorArray.length;
    }

    public String toString() {
        if (vectorArray == null)
            return null;
        return vectorArray.getClass().getName() + " " + vectorArray;
    }

    public T1[] plus(T1[] inputVector, T1[] whatToPlusVector){
        Vector <T1> result = new Vector<T1>();

        int index=0;
        for(T1 element : inputVector){
            result.setVectorValue(element, index);
            index++;
        }
        for(T1 element : whatToPlusVector){
            result.setVectorValue(element, index);
            index++;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Clean-Build your project. I dont see that error.

Comment: is the issue runtime or compile time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your no-arg constructor (the constructor that takes zero parameters) does not initialize the internal `vectorArray`. If the no-arg constructor is used, your `vectorArray` will remain `null`. In your `plus()` method you use the no-arg constructor so you can't set any elements of this `result` vector. You should create it with an initial array having length of:

```
int length = inputVector.getVectorLength() + whatToPlusVector.getVectorLength();
```

Since the array has to be of the generic type `T1` that's tricky. You can't just write `new T1[length]`.

For generic array creation, see this:
[How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-generic-array-creation)

So in your `plus()` method you should do like this:

```
int length = inputVector.getVectorLength() + whatToPlusVector.getVectorLength();
// You need the class of T1 to be able to create an array of it:
Class<?> clazz = inputVector.getVector().getClass().getComponentType();

T1[] array=(T[])Array.newInstance(clazz, length);
Vector <T1> result = new Vector<>(array);
// And the rest of your plus() method.
```

And last: your `plus()` method is declared to return a `T1[]` so either return `result.getVector()` or declare it to return `Vector<T1>` and then you can return the `result` local variable whose type is `Vector<T1>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But can you explain me, why I cannot call, for example, "inputVector.getVectorLength()" from a plus() method? IDEA doesn't see this method and gives an error "cannot resolve method". From "main" I can call it correctly.

Comment: Your original code has been edited multiple times. I don't know how your code looks like now, so I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

For the error 'cannot resolve method setVectorValue', may be the class was confused with java.util.Vector.

Change the class name 'Vector' to 'VectorExample' or something, then try again.

Answer (score 0):

I expect `NullPointerException` as `vectorArray` is not initialized within default constructor and in the `plus()` method default constructor is called and `setVector()` is not. So in `setVectorValue()` you will get `NPE`.

Also there is an issue with the return type mismatch in `plus()`. It should be `Vector <T1>` instead of `T1[]`.

Sample code test the `NPE`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
    String[] v1 = {"Str1"};
    String[] v2 = {"Str2"};
    v = v.plus(v1, v2);
    System.out.println(v);
}
```